# How to extend laravels query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I need mysql insert ignore or/and on duplicate key update functionality, but sadly laravels query builder doesn't support it, so what would be the best way to extend laravel (grammar class or something similar) to achieve this?

I've temporarily edited the core with insert ignore instead of insert and it works fine, but that's obviously not the right solution.

Comment: Perhaps you should talk to Taylor about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, you can extends `DatabaseManager` class.

```
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;

class MyDatabase extends DatabaseManager {
     //... add your code
}
```

Next, you have to create service provider for your class, look: http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers

i.e

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyDatabaseServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('mydb', function()
        {
            return new MyDatabase();
        });
    }

}
```

next add service provider, open `config/app.php` and add element to provider

```
'providers' => array(
     //...
    'Your\Namespase\MyDatabaseServiceProvider'
```

By Now, I am pretty sure you can use it like

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
   $app['mydb']->table('your_table')->get(); //this will work !

} );
```

OR, if you want to then you can use facade. create your facade file first.

```
class MYDB extends Facade {

   protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'mydb'; }

}
```

add alias to `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => array(
    //...
    'MYDB'            => 'your\namespace\Facade\MYDB',
```

Now, you can use:

```
MYDB::table('your table')->get();
```

Good Luck !